# TracksChooserDialog not correctly displaying chosen track

Tags: android, chromecast

I have run into an issue where all of a sudden the TracksChooserDialog provided in the Chromecast Companion Library will not correctly show the chosen text track.
This used to work but all of a sudden it stopped.

I can see that that selecting a track succeeds successfully because my registered `OnTracksSelectedListener#onTrackSelected` method gets called with the newly selected track.

I have also verified that in VideoCastManager the result from calling  `RemoteMediaPlayer#setActiveMediaTracks` returns a successful status. I have tried this on a Nexus player as well as a chromecast device and on different networks.

Any idea why the receiver might not be returning the correct active track ids?

Comment: First, I am not sure what you mean when you say it doesn't correctly show the selected track; is it not showing anything selected? Is it showing the wrong track selected? Please clarify. Secondly, you might want to narrow it down further to see if it is an issue in CCL or in the data that CCL receives from the SDK.

Comment: The RemoteMediaPlayer is returning null when the CCL is calling `mRemoteMediaPlayer.getMediaStatus().getActiveTrackIds()` even directly after I set a new track and the logs say it has succeeded.

Comment: So you are getting a NPE?

Comment: No, the track dialog provided by the CCL library isn't showing the correct track as being selected. Because `mRemoteMediaPlayer.getMediaStatus().getActiveTrackIds()` returns null instead of the correct track id

Comment: Can you try CastVideos-android and see if that works fine? Are you using a custom receiver?

Comment: Yes I am using a custom receiver.

Comment: Try CastVideos-android

Comment: Same issue here with custom receiver too. Afaik we didn't change anything in our code and getActiveTracksIds() returns null now. We were using Play Services Cast 8.3.0 and mediaroute 23.1.1. Now using 9.0.2 and 23.3.0. Same issue with both. We're playing PlayReady / SmoothStreaming protected videos. I will try mentioned example.

Comment: Just to add - It looks like null is returned only if there is multiple audio tracks.